# vertx post call search domain query failed

Tags: java, webclient, vert.x

I have created an webClient as:

```
WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions();
WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx, options);
String host = "https://example.com/";
```

and I am trying to do a POST call of a json command as:

```
client.post(8080, host, "/api/executor/command")
.ssl(false)
.rxSendJson(jsonCmd)
.map((HttpResponse<Buffer> r) -> {
System.out.println("response: " + r.bodyAsString());}).toObservable();})
.doOnError( error -> System.err.println("The error message is: " + error.getMessage()))
```

But I get this error:

```
The error message is: Search domain query failed. Original hostname: 'https://example.com/' failed to resolve 'https://example.com/.lan' after 3 queries
```

While doing the same curl call on the terminal as:

```
curl  https://example.com/api/executor/command -XPOST --insecure  -d 'jsonCmd'
```

I don't get any error and the server responds me.
What am I doing wrong? I am a newby of vertx/java.

Thanks

Matteo

EDIT

I have added as recommended the options

```
options.setTrustAll(true);
```

and removed the println and now it seems to work, thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You post your query with cURL to port 443 using ssl (as HTTPS suggests, 443 is default HTTPS port).
Whereas you not only disable ssl (by using `ssl(false)`), but also using wrong port number and wrong hostname (you give URL instead of hostname, hostname wouldn't contain `https://` prefix). Your code should be like:

```
String host = "example.com";
client.post(443, host, "/api/executor/command")
    .ssl(true)
...and so on...
```

so that it matches what cURL is doing.

Comment: now I get a "Failed to create SSL connection" error

Comment: @MatteoPeluso are you using correct 443 port? What exactly the error is? Have you checked the documentation on HTTPS https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/#_using_https ?

Answer (score 2):

Next to what demitry already said you can't map() to a println due to it returning void so to me this code snippet won't compile so I think you've missed something there.

But mainly it fails due to ssl and port being wrong. Set the options for `setTrustAll` tot true if you don't want the client to verify the certificate(s).

It will do the same thing as in your curl command with `--insecure`